# Play Test - Data persistence issues - POSTed data is not available when using GET

Tags: java, junit, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a Play 2.0 based RESTful API implementation and when I'm trying to run the test cases (CRUD operations), I see the POSTed request content (Successful 201 response) is not available when I do a GET operation in subsequent test case.

Please take a look at my JUnit test class -

```
public class TagTest {

public static FakeApplication app;

private static String AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization";
private static String AUTH_VALUE = "Basic a25paadsfdfasdfdsfasdmeSQxMjM=";
private static int tagId = 0;

private static Map<String, String> postDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
private static Map<String, String> updateDataMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
private static String searchText = null;

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() {
    // Set up new FakeApplication before running any tests
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();
    Helpers.start(app);
    postDataMap.put("text", "Created");
    updateDataMap.put("text", "Updated");
    searchText = "Date"; // case insensitive substring pattern for "Updated"
}

@Test
public void createTagTest() {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();

    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JsonNode json = Json.toJson(postDataMap);

            FakeRequest request=new FakeRequest().withJsonBody(json);
            Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.createTag(),request.withHeader(TagTest.AUTH_HEADER, TagTest.AUTH_VALUE));

            Map<String, String> headerMap = Helpers.headers(result);
            String location = headerMap.get(Helpers.LOCATION);
            String tagIdStr = location.replace("/tags/","");
            try {
                tagId = Integer.parseInt(tagIdStr);
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.CREATED);
                System.out.println("Tag Id : "+tagId+" Location : "+headerMap.get(Helpers.LOCATION)); // Here I'm getting resource URI from API which means it is successful run

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Inside NumberFormatException");
                e.printStackTrace();
                assertThat(0).isEqualTo(1);
            }
            System.out.println("createTagTest is successful");
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void getTagTest() {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();

    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest();
            Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.getTag(tagId), request.withHeader(TagTest.AUTH_HEADER, TagTest.AUTH_VALUE));
            String content = contentAsString(result);
            if(content.length()==0) {
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.NO_CONTENT);
            } else {
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.OK);
            }
            System.out.println("getTagTest is successful");
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void updateTagTest() {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();

    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            JsonNode json = Json.toJson(updateDataMap);
            FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest().withJsonBody(json);
            Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.updateTag(tagId), 
                                        request.withHeader(TagTest.AUTH_HEADER, TagTest.AUTH_VALUE));
            assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.OK);
            System.out.println("updateTagTest is successful");
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void getAllTagsTest() {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();

    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest();
            Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.getAllTags(null), request.withHeader(TagTest.AUTH_HEADER, TagTest.AUTH_VALUE));
            String content = contentAsString(result);
            System.out.println(content);
            if(content.length()==0) {
                System.out.println("No content");
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.NO_CONTENT);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Content");
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.OK);
            }
            System.out.println("getAllTagsTest is successful");
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void getTagsByTextTest() {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();

    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest();
            Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.getAllTags(searchText), request.withHeader(TagTest.AUTH_HEADER, TagTest.AUTH_VALUE));
            String content = contentAsString(result);
            if(content.length()==0) {
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.NO_CONTENT);
            } else {
                assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.OK);
            }
            System.out.println("getAllTagsByTextTest is successful");
        }
    });
}

@Test
public void deleteTagTest() {
    app = Helpers.fakeApplication();

    running(fakeApplication(), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            FakeRequest request = new FakeRequest();
            Result result = callAction(controllers.routes.ref.Application.deleteTag(tagId), request.withHeader(TagTest.AUTH_HEADER, TagTest.AUTH_VALUE));
            assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.OK);
            System.out.println("deleteTagTest is successful");
        }
    });
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() {
    // Stop FakeApplication after all tests complete
    Helpers.stop(app);
}
}
```

When I run the test, Tag is created but it was not picked up in the subsequent test when trying to do GET /tags/1 and resulted in 204 No content.

Please throw some light what could be the reason behind this. Another observation is, it worked yesterday and all of a sudden this issue has come into picture.

Great help if someone can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: I see that the In Memory Database I'm using perhaps being refreshed for every test case I run in the application. When I use a non - in memory DB (e.g. MySQL) the tests are working fine. Still need to investigate why the data is getting refreshed for every test run in IMDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit does not support an ordered sequence of test methods. That's a feature--not a bug. Tests should be independent. As a result, you can't guarantee that `getTagTest` comes after `createTagTest`. Sometimes it will; sometimes it won't.

The individual operations should have their own test fixtures with the appropriate preconditions defined with `@BeforeClass`.

If you insist on a defined order, then use `dependsOnMethods` in [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html).

Comment: Thanks Vidya! Your point is valid but when I observe the console log, I see the test runs in the order of the methods I declared in the class. Not sure if the log displays the results in a random order.

Comment: I see that the In Memory Database I'm using perhaps being refreshed for every test case I run in the application. When I use a non - in memory DB (e.g. MySQL) the tests are working fine. Still need to investigate why the data is getting refreshed for every test run in IMDB.